# CSS vertically align components within BootsFaces row

Tags: html, css

I have a BootFaces JSF-generated login form but I can't seem to get the span's to line up vertically in the middle with the input fields.

This is how the login form currently looks:

[image: Login layout showing desired vertical alignment]

Here is the HTML that is generated for this particular form:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bsf.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
           <input type="hidden" name="loginForm" value="loginForm" />
           <div id="loginForm:j_idt18" class="row">
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt19" class="col-md-4"><span class="pull-right">Username:</span></div>
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt21" class="col-md-4">
                 <div id="loginForm:username" class="form-group"><input id="input_loginForm:username" name="input_loginForm:username" type="text" class="form-control bf-no-message" placeholder="Username" /></div>
              </div>
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt22" class="message col-md-4 ">
                 <div id="loginForm:j_idt23"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" data-container="body" title="This password has fancy error messages." id="loginForm:j_idt24" class="row">
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt25" class="col-md-4"><span class="pull-right">Password:</span></div>
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt27" class="col-md-4">
                 <div id="loginForm:password" class="form-group"><input id="input_loginForm:password" name="input_loginForm:password" type="password" class="form-control bf-no-message" placeholder="Password" /></div>
              </div>
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt28" class="message col-md-4 ">
                 <div id="loginForm:j_idt29"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div id="loginForm:j_idt30" class="row">
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt31" class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4"><button type="submit" id="loginForm:j_idt32" name="loginForm:j_idt32" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%">Login</button></div>
              <div id="loginForm:j_idt33" class="col-md-2"><button type="submit" id="loginForm:j_idt34" name="loginForm:j_idt34" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%">Forgotten password?</button></div>
           </div>
           <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:1" value="-5586558823054575095:3125033607536646469" autocomplete="off" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are the two CSS files belonging to BootFaces:

[bsf.css](http://pastebin.com/6DT54die)

[core.css](http://pastebin.com/KfLcRZpY)

Comment: @BalusC, yes you are right, providing an MCVE of the HTML and CSS would be more helpful. I have modified the question and put links to the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the height will remain consistent, you can vertically center text by specifying both a height and line-height:

```
.vertical-center {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Just apply that class to the username and password text fields. The values should reflect the height of the input fields.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was hoping there might be a way to do it without hard coding the values. If no other answers come along shortly, I'll accept this as the answer

Comment: Probably the bug is caused by the wrong markup BootsFaces 0.9.1 and below generate. Have a look at the GitHub issue to track progress (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/475).

Comment: Glad to hear that the solution fixed your problem! Just checking if you managed to find a solution to the problem without using hard-coded values? If not, if you could please remember to mark this answer as correct. Some users filter questions for ones that are unanswered, and as such, remembering to pick an answer to a question helps to filter out problems that have already been sorted. Cheers! :)